# How to use p5.js sound library preload with Node.js (and create-react-app)

Tags: node.js, p5.js

I am trying to use p5.js sound library in Node.js and the preload function simply throws an (understandable) error saying that it is not being used. How do I use the preload function in Node ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import p5 from "p5";
import 'p5/lib/addons/p5.dom';
import "p5/lib/addons/p5.sound";
import sound from "./audio/song.mp3";
import './App.css';

let song;

function preload() { // @preload is required by P5.js
    p5.soundFormats('mp3', 'ogg');
    song = p5.loadSound(sound);
}






class App extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <div className="App">

               <button>Click me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: My guess is you probably want to use instance mode. See [this guide](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode) for more info.

Comment: Perfect. I'll give this a try. Thanks

Comment: Let me know if that worked out. If so I'll expand my comment into an answer.

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, P5.js uses **global mode**, which means that it puts functions and variables in the global scope. That's what you're doing with your `preload()` function.

The problem is, this doesn't always play nice with other libraries, and it looks like it's causing problems with `node.js`.

You can fix this problem using **instance mode**, which packages up the P5.js functions in an object that you can use instead of putting everything in the global scope. Here's a simple example:

```
var s = function( sketch ) {

  var x = 100; 
  var y = 100;

  sketch.setup = function() {
    sketch.createCanvas(200, 200);
  };

  sketch.draw = function() {
    sketch.background(0);
    sketch.fill(255);
    sketch.rect(x,y,50,50);
  };
};

var myp5 = new p5(s);
```

You can find more information in [this guide](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/wiki/Global-and-instance-mode).